# TempDB drive Full - Procedure needs much performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, tempdb

following situation: We have an azure server with db and the TempDB drive ran full. At this moment we could find a process with much resources need in activity monitor. The process was not killable cause the rollback couldn't be done cause of the full drive.

Now I have two questions:

1. Can the process be the cause of the huge tempdb files?
2. Can someone explain why the process needs so much resources?

Attach you find a screenshot of the activity monitor and the code of the procedure.

The procedure is started every 10 seconds with SQL Server agent. The loop inside the procedure is not that nice but we needed the statistics and it run well for the last 3 weeks.

[image]

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Log_Blocking_Processes
AS
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Log_Blocked_Processes', 'U') IS NULL
        BEGIN
            SELECT  GETDATE() as Tag,
                    db.name DBName,
                    tl.request_session_id,
                    wt.blocking_session_id,
                    OBJECT_NAME(p.OBJECT_ID) BlockedObjectName,
                    tl.resource_type,
                    h1.TEXT AS RequestingText,
                    h2.TEXT AS BlockingText,
                    tl.request_mode,
                    er.transaction_id as Requesting_Transaction_ID,
                    tst.transaction_id as Blocking_Transaction_ID,
                    tat.name as Blocking_Transaction_Name,
                    er.wait_time/1000 as Wait_Time_SEC
            INTO Log_Blocked_Processes
            FROM sys.dm_tran_locks AS tl
            INNER JOIN sys.databases db ON db.database_id = tl.resource_database_id
            INNER JOIN sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks AS wt ON tl.lock_owner_address = wt.resource_address
            INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p ON p.hobt_id = tl.resource_associated_entity_id
            INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections ec1 ON ec1.session_id = tl.request_session_id
            INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections ec2 ON ec2.session_id = wt.blocking_session_id
            INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests er ON er.session_id = tl.request_session_id AND er.blocking_session_id = wt.blocking_session_id AND er.blocking_session_id <> 0
            INNER JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions tst ON tst.session_id = wt.blocking_session_id
            INNER JOIN sys.dm_tran_active_transactions tat ON tat.transaction_id = tst.transaction_id
            CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec1.most_recent_sql_handle) AS h1
            CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec2.most_recent_sql_handle) AS h2
            WHERE db.database_id = DB_ID();

            RETURN;
        END;

    DECLARE @DBName nvarchar(128),
            @request_session_id int,
            @blocking_session_id smallint,
            @BlockedObjectName nvarchar(128),
            @resource_type nvarchar(60),
            @RequestingText nvarchar(MAX),
            @BlockingText nvarchar(MAX),
            @request_mode nvarchar(60),
            @Requesting_Transaction_ID bigint,
            @Blocking_Transaction_ID bigint,
            @Blocking_Transaction_Name nvarchar(32),
            @Wait_Time_SEC int,
            @Tag DATE,
            @Mycount int,
            @LastInsertDay DATE,
            @counter int = 1;

    DECLARE blocked_processes_cursor CURSOR FOR   
        SELECT  cast(GETDATE() as DATE) as Tag,
                db.name DBName,
                tl.request_session_id,
                wt.blocking_session_id,
                OBJECT_NAME(p.OBJECT_ID) BlockedObjectName,
                tl.resource_type,
                h1.TEXT AS RequestingText,
                h2.TEXT AS BlockingText,
                tl.request_mode,
                er.transaction_id as Requesting_Transaction_ID,
                tst.transaction_id as Blocking_Transaction_ID,
                tat.name as Blocking_Transaction_Name,
                er.wait_time/1000 as Wait_Time_SEC
        FROM sys.dm_tran_locks AS tl
        INNER JOIN sys.databases db ON db.database_id = tl.resource_database_id
        INNER JOIN sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks AS wt ON tl.lock_owner_address = wt.resource_address
        INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p ON p.hobt_id = tl.resource_associated_entity_id
        INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections ec1 ON ec1.session_id = tl.request_session_id
        INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections ec2 ON ec2.session_id = wt.blocking_session_id
        INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests er ON er.session_id = tl.request_session_id AND er.blocking_session_id = wt.blocking_session_id AND er.blocking_session_id <> 0
        INNER JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions tst ON tst.session_id = wt.blocking_session_id
        INNER JOIN sys.dm_tran_active_transactions tat ON tat.transaction_id = tst.transaction_id
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec1.most_recent_sql_handle) AS h1
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec2.most_recent_sql_handle) AS h2
        WHERE db.database_id = DB_ID();

    WHILE @counter <= 4
    BEGIN
        OPEN blocked_processes_cursor  
        FETCH NEXT FROM blocked_processes_cursor INTO @Tag, @DBName, @request_session_id, @blocking_session_id, @BlockedObjectName, @resource_type, @RequestingText, @BlockingText, @request_mode, @Requesting_Transaction_ID, @Blocking_Transaction_ID, @Blocking_Transaction_Name, @Wait_Time_SEC;

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
        BEGIN
            SELECT @Mycount = count(*), @LastInsertDay = cast(max(Tag) as date) FROM Log_Blocked_Processes WHERE Requesting_Transaction_ID = @Requesting_Transaction_ID AND Blocking_Transaction_ID = @Blocking_Transaction_ID;
            IF @Mycount > 0 AND @LastInsertDay = cast(getdate() as date)
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE Log_Blocked_Processes
                    SET Wait_Time_SEC = @Wait_Time_SEC
                    WHERE Requesting_Transaction_ID = @Requesting_Transaction_ID
                    AND Blocking_Transaction_ID = @Blocking_Transaction_ID;
                END;
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO [Log_Blocked_Processes]([Tag],[DBName],[request_session_id],[blocking_session_id],[BlockedObjectName],[resource_type],[RequestingText],[BlockingText],[request_mode],[Requesting_Transaction_ID],[Blocking_Transaction_ID],[Blocking_Transaction_Name],[Wait_Time_SEC])
                    VALUES(GETDATE(),@DBName,@request_session_id,@blocking_session_id,@BlockedObjectName,@resource_type,@RequestingText,@BlockingText,@request_mode,@Requesting_Transaction_ID,@Blocking_Transaction_ID,@Blocking_Transaction_Name,@Wait_Time_SEC)
                END;

            FETCH NEXT FROM blocked_processes_cursor INTO @Tag, @DBName, @request_session_id, @blocking_session_id, @BlockedObjectName, @resource_type, @RequestingText, @BlockingText, @request_mode, @Requesting_Transaction_ID, @Blocking_Transaction_ID, @Blocking_Transaction_Name, @Wait_Time_SEC;
        END;

        SET @counter = @counter + 1;
        CLOSE blocked_processes_cursor;
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';
    END;

    DEALLOCATE blocked_processes_cursor;
END;
```

Comment: Depending on count of rows the process can cause huge using tempdb, your cursor's data is stored in tempdb. RequestingText and BlockingText can be big enough because they are full texts of a stored procedure, not only one statement. Why don't you use Extended Events to get blocked_process_report? It works like a charm.

Comment: I second extended events for this type of thing. And get in the habit that when you start thinking RBAR (row by agonizing row) you need to rethink what you are doing. You have nested loops here to update some data. This could be done in a single update statement instead of a cursor.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. @DenisRubashkin sounds reasonable. In the last 3 weeks it logged just 3 events a day so I didnt expect that it could cause problems. Up to now I didnt know Extended Events but I will check this. @ Sean Lange Yeah you are right. Single update would have been the better solution.